# Getting 3 errors in React Native project 1: React Native CLI error 2: Android development environment error 3:emulator error

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

After cloning a React Native project and setting the all the requirements in android studio I am getting 3 errors in the terminal after running the command "react-native run-android".

Can anyone please help me! How to fix these errors.

1) error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-camera (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-camera")

2) error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run C
LI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

3) error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

*This react native project is running fine on IMac devices, Only getting error on windows Os using tool Android Studio.*